# "Array out of bounds" error when trying to add subview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently writing an app and I'm experiencing a problem that seems to be caused by code that I did not write (i.e., Apple's classes). I create an instance of a subclass of `UIViewController` that I wrote. I add it as a child view controller of another custom view controller. Then, when I try to add this new view controller's view as a subview of the parent view controller's view I get a crash with this error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

I have tested and determined that the problem is specifically cause by trying to add the view as a subview. I reference the view in an `NSLog` just to make sure that it isn't simply the act of referencing it that's causing the error. I've tried adding the view as a subview of different views and that also crashed, so the problem is not with the parent view. Finally, I have tried to add a different view as a subview to the parent view and that did work, further proving that the parent view is fine, and that the prospective subview is at fault. The code where I allocate it is this:

```
ScheduleSelectorViewController* selector = [[ScheduleSelectorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScheduleSelectorViewController" bundle:nil];
```

This has always worked for me. I don't know what it is I've changed. I don't know enough about the inner workings of subview hierarchy to know which array is empty and is causing this crash, so if anyone can help me out I would be extremely grateful.

If there's any other information I could supply that would help let me know.

UPDATE:

Here is the code where it crashes. I have placed NSLogs to indicate the line at which it breaks.

```
- (void) addViewControllerToStack:(UIViewController *)controller withKey:(NSString *)key
{
```

if ( !self.stack ) {
    self.stack = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}

NSLog(@"subviews %@", [controller.view subviews]);



[[controller view] setFrame:offScreenFrame];
[self addChildViewController:controller];


NSLog(@"code gets to here");

[self.view addSubview:controller.view];

NSLog(@"but not to here");


[self.view bringSubviewToFront:controller.view];
[self.stack setObject:controller forKey:key];
[self.stackKeys addObject:key];
}

For the record, the subviews array is not nil.

Comment: Share what line of your code causes the exception to be thrown.

Comment: In the left pane, select the breakpoint navigator (icon looks like a chevron).  Add an "all exceptions" breakpoint.  (plus sign at the very bottom left).  Run again, and see what source line it stops on.  This is the line throwing the exception.  It looks like you're asking for a member of an empty array.

Comment: I've updated the post, does anyone have any suggestions? @CarlVeazey

Comment: and @Innsmouth ......

Comment: That logging is really not sufficient - did you follow the directions for setting an exception breakpoint?

Comment: Does your container subclass override addChildViewController: ?  If so, does the overridden method call super?  Writing your own container is kind of an advanced topic.  Have you studied a couple examples?

Comment: @danh no I do not override addChildViewController: . I haven't studied any examples, I was just told about the method by my teacher and it has always worked to do the thing I am trying to do, namely, to make two views visible at the same time while dividing their management between two classes.

Comment: @CarlVeazey yes I added the exception breakpoint. It says the first exception is thrown when I set the controller view to offScreenFrame

Comment: The line [self addChildViewController:controller]; implies that you're building a container vc, but maybe you're not?  Can you tell me the superclass of the class that contains that line?  Can you comment that line out and see how the behavior changes?

Comment: @danh the class that contains the code that I have posted inherits from UIViewController. And if I comment out the line that adds it as a subview the code no longer crashes

Comment: I have resolved the problem and I'm not actually sure what I did which is my least favorite way for that to happen but anyway thanks for all the help

Comment: Glad it's resolved.  The concept here is that addChildViewControler is pretty specialized, for use when creating a containerViewController, which is rare.  You only need to add views from other vcs, not make those other vcs child vcs.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have set *view's*`.hidden = YES;` somewhere

I was pulling my hair for more than hour to find out I was hiding my pager control and try to set the `pageIndicatorTintColor` property later which also throw array out of bounds issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did not override `init`/ `initWithNibName` methods in `ScheduleSelectorViewController` without calling the `super` methods.

And of course you can always print out `[self.view subviews]` for parent view in console to understand if subview array is whether `nil`. If it is nil you should initiate it before adding any views.